# Inverse of cosh(x)

Tags: calculus, inverse, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

My goal is to find the inverse of $y=\cosh(x)$

Therefore:
$$x=\cosh(y)=\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2}=\frac{e^{2y}+1}{2e^y}$$
If we define $k=e^y$ then:
$$k^2-2xk+1=0$$
$$k=e^{y}=x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
$$y=\ln(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})=\cosh^{-1}(x)$$

However, apparently: $\cosh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$ is right, but NOT $\cosh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$

What step did I miss?

Comment: The function $\cosh$ is even, and does not have an inverse. But if we restrict $\cosh$ to the interval $[0,\infty]$ (the usual choice), the inverse function has the $+$. If we restrict to the interval $(-\infty,0]$, then $-$ is right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is also positive for $x>1$

Comment: The $\ln$ of it is not positive.

Comment: Note that in your last two lines it should be $\cosh^{-1} x$, not $\cosh x$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function $\cosh$ is even, so formally speaking it does not have an inverse, for basically the same reason that the function $g(t)=t^2$ does not have an inverse.

But if we restrict the domain of $\cosh$ suitably, then there is an inverse. The usual definition of $\cosh^{-1}x$ is that it is the **non-negative** number whose $\cosh$ is $x$.

Note that for $x\gt 1$, we have
$$x-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\lt 1,$$
and therefore $\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})\lt 0$ whereas we were looking for the *non-negative* $y$ which would satisfy the inverse equation.
Thus, $y=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$ is not the *non-negative* number whose $\cosh$ is $x$.

*Remark:* If one defined $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ as the non-positive number whose $\cosh$ is $x$, then the answer $\ln(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$ would be the right one.